# PHP Try-Catch Failing to Catch (Not a 'Warning')

Tags: php, try-catch

I have some PHP code that should cause and catch two exceptions:

```
try{
    @$this->connector->connect(); // Suppress the default warning (doesn't effect 'throw')
} catch(BadArgumentException $e) {} // Works, no error, following code executes.

try{
    @$this->connector->connect(array('user' => 'Doesn\'t exist', 'pass' => 'invalid'));
} catch(AuthenticationException $e) {} // DOESN'T WORK - Passed to the exception handler.

echo 'Not executed!'; // This isn't executed.
```

I have tried generalising them to `catch(Exception $e)` but get the same problem... no idea why.

Any help?

Comment: What exception or error is it generating? Are you sure it isn't a parser error?

Comment: Have you tried running the code outside of the `try` blocks?  What exception gets thrown?

Comment: I generalised it right down to two functions `throw1()` and `throw2()` that throw exceptions and two try/catches to run them... and it works!  So must be an issue at a lower level, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out it was a namespacing problem: it seems PHP doesn't complain when you try and `use` a non-existant namespaced element (in this case `use Framework\AuthenticationException` when really I needed `use Framework\Connector\AuthenticationException`).  Everything's peachy now :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should also know that using @ is EXTREMELY slow in PHP. Please, please, please don't use it in your production code.

Comment: Could you provide any explanation as to why @ is slow and should be avoided?

Comment: Google "php error suppression performance": http://www.phpdeveloping.co.za/error-handling/error-suppression-operator.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)  This is only for testing though, I try and avoid error suppression in 'real' code.